# jquery lazy load

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, groovy

Im trying to create a div that will use jquery's lazy load to load images coming in from linkedIn.  When I look at the examples found online, they seem to work fine with my browser, but when i try to add it, it doesnt seem to work. I'm not sure if it matters, but i'm developing in Groovy/grails. here is the code i have so far, before rendering:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'js',file:'jquery.lazyload.js')}">  

  </script>     
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
   ....
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("img").lazyload({
placeholder : "/mgr/images/spinner.gif" 
 });

 </script>
   ....
</head>
<body>
 <div style="width: 150px; height:200px; border:1px solid red; overflow:auto;">
 <g:each in="${Friends}" status="i" var="Friends">  
   <img original=${Friends[3]} src="/mgr/images/spinner.gif">
</g:each>
   </div>
```

This code will only draw the div and display the /mgr/images/spinner.gif image but not the original image.  Is there something i'm missing?

thanks for your help
jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you include the plugin file after the jQuery core file. That way the plugin can extend the jQuery core.

Change:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'js',file:'jquery.lazyload.js')}">  

  </script>     
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

To:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'js',file:'jquery.lazyload.js')}"></script>
```

I would also recommend trying to use the newest jQuery core file you can. It may break old plugins but it's well worth attempting as with each update to jQuery come performance enhancements.

[jQuery 1.6.4 from Google CDN](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js).

[jQuery 1.6.4 from jQuery's CDN](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js).

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to load some html not just for images using lazy loading plugin you can do easy like that on lazy callbacks
this option "enableThrottle: false", is to ensure your callback is always executed, I had some issues because of this ... sometimes lazy loading wasn't working..

to html add "class="lazy" data-src=" " to an element to section/div/img to call when is displayed to add new html

```
>  $('.lazy').Lazy({
>       chainable: false,
>       enableThrottle: false,
>       onFinishedAll: function () {
>        // do what you need ajax call or other 
>       },
>       beforeLoad: function () {
>            // do what you need ajax call or other 
>       },
>       afterLoad: function () {
>         // do what you need ajax call or other 
>       },
>       onError: function () {
>         console.log('could not be loaded');
>       }
>     });
```